# Subscripts in 'user-defined' cell formatting

Tags: formatting, cell, libreoffice-calc

In libreoffice calc, I use **Format cells > Number > User-defined > Format code > 0.000 “kg”** to display 200 kg in the cell A1. Now, in cell A2, I can use the formula : A1 x 2 and obtain 400. This is very convenient. Just like this, in the format code **0.000 “CA”**, Is it possible to display 'A' as the subscript. Please give your suggestions. Thanks.

Edit: I tried using the unicode. It works well inside the cell. But cannot be used in the format cell dialogue box. The screenshot is attached below.  The problems are marked with a red rectangle and a green arrow. Please verify it.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear. When you write *"Is it possible to display 'A' as the subscript"* do you mean exactly `A`? or `a` will suit you? In the first case, it seems to me that you will not achieve success. If you are satisfied with "Cₐ", then just use U+2090 - `0.000" Cₐ"`. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) assures that `A` can only occur in superscript

Comment: @JohnSUN Thanks for the comment. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start typing the format code simply into the cell: `0.000 "C`

[image: Step 1]

Now choose [Insert-Special Character...](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/01/04100000.html)

[image: Step 2]

Use this tool to find and select the desired symbol

[image: Step 3]

Complete the cell input

[image: Step 4]

Copy the result and paste it as format code in the [Format-Cells...](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/05020000.html) window

[image: Step 5]

This is a general principle for constructing unusual format codes using special characters. Of course, you can simply copy this particular line of format code directly from StackOverflow - `0.000" Cₐ"`